# How to fix "No matching distribution found for pip2"?

Tags: python, pip

```
└─( 2 ) ❱❱❱ pip install pip2                                                                      +2964 12:12 ❰─┘
Collecting pip2
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip2
```

Searched everywhere for clues but none helped. Installed all python stuff via apt-get here. Thanks!

By the way, the commands pip and pip2 point to the same executable it seems:

```
┌─( ~ )─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────( @M1 )─┐
└─( 2 ) ❱❱❱ pip --version                                                                         +2972 12:07 ❰─┘
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)

┌─( ~ )─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────( @M1 )─┐
└─( 2 ) ❱❱❱ pip2 --version                                                                        +2973 12:07 ❰─┘
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

Furthermore also have pip3 installed

```
┌─( ~ )─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────( @M1 )─┐
└─( 2 ) ❱❱❱ pip3 --version                                                                        +2977 12:10 ❰─┘
pip 9.0.1
```

from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.5)

Makes me wonder which one I should be using to manage pip package?

Comment: what told you to install `pip2`? (there's no such thing -- in fact, pip went from version 1.5 straight to 6)

Comment: hmm, i am confused. i have two commands, pip and pip2 both. i have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to install pip for Python 2.X?  If so, it's just pip (which you already have).

You can update pip to the latest version with:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Are you assuming that since Python 3.X has pip3 that you need pip2 for Python 2.X?  If so, that is just pip.

If you would like additional details, you can check out:  [pip.pypa.io](https://pip.pypa.io//en/latest/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: yeah, already have updated pip to latest. are you saying it does not matter whether i am using pip or pip2 for python2.x ? then why so and not remove one? how could this happen? confusing ...

Comment: you're pip and pip2 are likely the same and will operate against your Python 2.x distro.  Since you have a Python 3.x installed as well, you would use pip3 to make sure it operates against your Python 3.x distro.  Do a [pip freeze] and a [pip2 freeze] you should should see the same packages.  Then do a [pip3 freeze] and you should see packages installed for Python 3.x.  Look at the link I gave you in my initial response.  You don't install pip2, you install pip.